# OpenAM: Is there a way way to programmatically modify maxSessionTime attribute?

Tags: opensso

I've tried researching about custom authentication modules and authentication post processing, but didn't find anything.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by programmatically?  Can it be via the commandline?

Answer (score 1):

By programmatically I meant to set this value based on some user attributes. Actually I found a way, using a Custom Condition inside a Policy. The ConditionDecision class (wich is the getConditionDecision() Condition´s interface response) allows to set a specific Session TTL.

More about the Policy Evaluation API here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19681-01/820-3748/6nf8sa0b1/index.html